# Unable to read CD contents after mounting

Tags: usb, data-cd

I'm attempting to mount a CD drive (via USB) and read the contents of the CD in the drive. I'm able to mount the drive fine, but I'm unable to read the contents. Here's what I've done:

```
$ lsblk
NAME           MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sr0             11:0    1 881.6M  0 rom  

$ sudo mount -t iso9660 -o ro /dev/sr0 /mnt/cd

$ lsblk
NAME           MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sr0             11:0    1 881.6M  0 rom   /mnt/cd

$ ls /mnt/cd/
ls: cannot open directory '/mnt/cd': Permission denied
```

I've also tried as root, but without any luck. `dmesg` shows

```
[1422983.554740] ISO 9660 Extensions: Microsoft Joliet Level 3
[1422983.670987] ISO 9660 Extensions: RRIP_1991A
```

The CD contains a program to install a software program on windows, if that matters.

Is there a way to debug what might be going on here? Any thoughts on why this appears to mount fine, but I'm not able to read the contents?

---

## Edit

The output of `ls -l /mnt` is:

```
drwx------ 7 nobody root  4.0K Jun 22  2016 cd
```

However, I've also tried

```
$ sudo ls /mnt/cd
ls: cannot open directory '/mnt/cd': Permission denied
```

Comment: Can you post the output of `ls -l /mnt`? If you have mounted the CD as root, it may be that your ordinary user is not allowed to access it.

Comment: What did you try as root?

Comment: @AdminBee I've updated the question. I tried to access the mount point as root too, but that didn't work.

Comment: @stoney I tried `sudo ls /mnt/cd`.

Comment: I also tried changing to the root user with `su` and then `cd`ing into the directory but I'm not sure if that's really different from the first attempt.

Comment: Yeah, if the group doesn't have access right, and the user is nobody, then no-one can access that drive ..

Comment: ok following: `sudo umount /mnt/cd` - `sudo chmod 755 /mnt/cd` - `sudo chown root /mnt/cd` - `sudo mount -t iso9660 /dev/sr0 /mnt/cd` should do it.

Comment: @stoney unfortunately that didn't work. When I check the permissions of the directory before mounting everything looks good (`drwxr-xr-x 1 root users`), but after mounting it's still `drwx------ 7 nobody root`. I do now see the following message when mounting, however: `mount: /mnt/cd: WARNING: source write-protected, mounted read-only.`

Comment: thats pretty ok. after mounting, does `sudo chmod 755 /mnt/cd` work (as in: no error, directory accessible)? And try to mount with `-o user` flag

Comment: No luck with either of those unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ISO 9660 Extensions: RRIP_1991A
```

This message indicates the CD was created with Rock Ridge extensions, meaning that the files and directories within can have Unix-style user/group IDs and permissions assigned to them. Unless the permissions are set world-readable, you may have trouble reading the CD if it does not happen to have UID/GID numbers matching your system's.

So, you will need to override the UID/GID information. You can do it by adding some mount options:

```
sudo mount -t iso9660 -o ro,uid=$(id -u),gid=$(id -g) /dev/sr0 /mnt/cd
```

Note: no spaces before or after the commas!

Before executing the `sudo` command line, your shell will replace the `$( ... )` parts by running the commands inside the parentheses and replacing the expressions with the results of those commands. Only after this is done, the `sudo mount ...` will execute.
The result will be that those `uid=` and `gid=` options will be auto-filled by the actual UID/GID values of your regular non-root user account.

Now, you will be treated as the owner of any files on the CD, and unless the CD has totally insane permissions, you should be able to read everything on it without being root.

Comment: That did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

You need execute privileges to access the directory, so you need to

`sudo chmod 775 /mnt/cd`

`cd /mnt/cd`

Comment: This has the same result as the comments mentioned in the original question. Specifically, I get the message `chmod: changing permissions of '/mnt/cd': Read-only file system` and the permissions of the mount point do not change.